# background-color: white in IE7 appears transparent

Tags: css, background, internet-explorer-7, transparent

Yup, you just read that.

My Googling gave me tons of results where people wanted a transparent background, and it appeared white.

Today, I stumbled upon the opposite ! It seems to be a real bug since I was able to reproduce it in a JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/qtByH/

The background-color is set to red by default, and everything works fine. If you change it to white and re-run the fiddle (using IE7, of course), the background remains transparent when you hover the link.

Any thoughts ?

**Edit :** here is the code in case the fiddle vanishes away.

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Test</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS :

```
body { background-color: green; }
a:hover { background-color: red; }
```

Comment: dear see the fiddle in IE7 this will show you white background on hover. Unnecessary html elements removed also.

Comment: Improve the question, in particular the tag "white" [present in the question at the moment of typing this comment] refers to an UI automation framework, not the color white. Also, the relevant code will be appreciated (as stackoverflow can't depend on jsfiddle's availability).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in my comment, `zoom: 1;` was the way to go (must have been yet another `hasLayout` issue).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have an HTML document inside another HTML document, which probably makes the browser revert to quirks mode. The JsFiddle site already adds a document around the HTML code, so you should not enter a complete HTML document.

http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/qtByH/3/

Comment: Hmm... I didn't know about it, thank you.

This indeed is solved on the Fiddle, but still not on the webpage I'm working on. I'm viewing this through IE8 in IE7-emulation mode, and IE's development toolbar says the page isn't rendered in Quirks mode. I always assumed this was reliable info, am I wrong ?

Comment: Sorry for double posting, I waited too long for a second edit : the background-color works as long as it's not pure white (#FFFFFE is shown, #FFFFFF is not). That's really weird.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a chroma filter somewhere?

```
filter: Chroma(color='#ffffff');
```

or

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(color='#ffffff');
```

or something like that?

A chroma filter set's a color to be transparent.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532982(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Nope. But I solved the issue :

To this day, I had never encountered a situation where adding zoom: 1; to an element actually fixed anything in IE7. This day has now come. Sorry for posting before I actually thought about this.

For the record, I got the answer from some topic I finally encountered while doing some more Googling : http://archivist.incutio.com/viewlist/css-discuss/106689

Answer (score 0):

See the fiddle without unnecessary html code and demo for output:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qtByH/5/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qtByH/4/embedded/result/